# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) --Zabbix installation

Tags: mysql, zabbix

Zabbix Error at the time of installation on ubuntu 20.4

```
# mysql -u root -p 
Enter password:
```

b. Install Zabbix server, frontend, agent

```
# apt install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-frontend-php zabbix-apache-conf zabbix-sql-scripts zabbix-agent
```

**Solution:**

In the part of installation the MySQL-server packages is not available on documents, to avoid this error.
run below mention Command.

```
   # apt install mysql-server
   # systemctl status mysql
   # systemctl start mysql
```

Comment: It is OK to answer your own question. However pleae edit your question: Remove the soltion from the qyestion and add: When (...) I get the error `ERROR 2002 ...(2)`. How can I solve this?
You might edit the title (less words): "Zabbix installation, connecting to MySQL through socket."

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

In the part of installation the MySQL-server packages is not available on documents, to avoid this error. run below mention Command.

```
   #apt install mysql-server
   #systemctl status mysql
   #systemctl start mysql
```